# What are the chances of a malware being persistent if I dd to write system.img and userdata.img from twrp

Tags: malware, partitions, device-firmware, factory-image, mediatek

If I had a malware on my phone, say malware like xhelper, or strandhogg or something even critical than that, what are the chances of it being persistent even after using `dd` to write the **system.img** and **userdata.img** to the phone for eg `dd if=system.img of=/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system` to write system as brand new. Is it possible that the malware could snoop into `/cache` or `/nvdata` to attain persistence. Is it feasible to use `dd` to flash those partitions as well? Which places would a malware use to hide itself to maintain persistence even after stock image flashing?